# UINavigationBar Back button with no text, ever

Tags: cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

I have a requirement in a project that the UINavigationBar Back button should *never* have text in it, it should always just be a left arrow.

By default iOS is going to insert the title of the previous controller in there. Is there any way I can stop this from happening across the whole app?

(I know I can do this screen by screen, but I'm working on an existing app with A LOT of screens it and this would be a big job)

Comment: This is default action provided by the apple, i think you will need to go for custom button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't stop it from happening across the whole app, you'll have to set it manually in each controller. You could use a category on UIViewController and call that method in each controller, which will get you down to 1 line of code that doesn't have to change if you change your approach. Still sucks, I know. Also, you will probably have issues with Apple if you do that. We tried that in one of our apps and when I showed it to the Apple guys at WWDC '13 they flat out told me they would reject the app if I submitted it that way. YMMV

Comment: Interesting point about Apple, will pass that on to the designers. If I can talk them out of the requirement that solves it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can always set an image of an arrow to left bar button of navigation bar

```
// ADDING IMAGE TO BUTTON

UIButton *refreshButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[refreshButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,30,30)];
[refreshButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow_image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
refreshButton.userInteractionEnabled=NO;

// ASSIGNING THE BUTTON WITH IMAGE TO LEFT BAR BUTTON

UIBarButtonItem *refreshBarButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:refreshButton] autorelease];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = refreshBarButton;
```

You will have to write this in each view controller in order to disable default left bar button.